# Java Serialization ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization

When an ArrayList in java is serialized, are the objects stored in it serialized with it?
Or do I have to get and serialize all of it's contents?

Answer (score 3):

When you serialise any object, it will generally serialise everything in it. Otherwise that object hasn't really been serialised.

As Vash points out, those objects have to implement `Serializable` for this to work, or you get a NotSerializableException.  Classes in the JDK already implement Serializable where it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to add the [serialization interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to those objects to. Otherwise you will not be able to serialize the ArrayList.

Comment: I ask this question implying that the ArrayList objects implement serializable.

Comment: This is not obvious, but if it so then ArrayList should be serialized with success.